# Turning MySQL Timestamp into R date format

Tags: mysql, r, ggplot2

I have a MySQL table where new entries are given a timestamp like this:

```
`timestamp` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

and looking like this:

```
2014-01-01 01:01:01
```

And I would like to be able to plot these timestamps in a ggplot2 scatterchart using:

```
[...]
if(myxaxis == "timestamp") {
   p = p + scale_x_datetime(as.POSIXct("xvalue"))                                                                                                                      
 }
 print(p)
[...]
```

I get an error:

```
Error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How can I transform my timestamp to the correct date format for ggplot2's `scale_x_date`?

Comment: Isn't it just the UNIX_TIMESTAMP divided by 86400 ?

Comment: Can you show us the actual string of the date that comes out of mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, it looks like the `as.POSIX` function is trying to work out what date and time the actual string "xvalue" is. If your date/time string is stored in a variable called xvalue, then try removing the double quotes:

```
p = p + scale_x_datetime(as.POSIXct(xvalue))
```